# Kotlin Spring dockerized app - message in response is missing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, kotlin, docker-compose

i have a problem with my spring boot app , so i have a simple @ControllerAdvice class that i am using for exception handling:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "Department with this id not found!")
@ExceptionHandler(DepartmentNotFoundException::class)
fun departmentNotFound(exception: DepartmentNotFoundException): ResponseEntity<String> {
    return ResponseEntity.notFound().build()
}
```

The problem is that if i start the app from intelijjide , in the response i receive the message or reason but if i start my app in a docker container i receive the response with corect status code just like if i started it locally from IDEA but without message.

Does someone encountered such a problem and do you have any hints where to look? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

server:
error:
include-message: always

So if you put this conf in your application.properties it will show you the message even in docker containariezed app